# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state' - Flask SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having a trouble with appending my values to an association table. I haven't fixed this issue ever since. I don't know if it's a problem with the relationship or with other things.

Here's my `association table`

```
item_tags_association_table = db.Table('item_tags_associations', db.Model.metadata,
            db.Column('item_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('items.id')),
            db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id')))
```

Here's my `Item` model

```
class Item(db.Model):
    # 1. Set the table name in plural form
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    # 2. Implemantation Attributes()
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80),nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text,nullable=False)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
    avatar_url = db.Column(db.String(500))
    bio = db.Column(db.String(240))
    #2019/07/23
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    category = db.relationship("Category", back_populates="items")
    tags = db.relationship("Tag", secondary=item_tags_association_table,
                            back_populates="items")
```

And here's my function to process the append that is actually inside the class Item as well.

```
def insert_tags(self, tag_list):
    for tag in tag_list:
        self.tags.append(tag)
```

Here's the `Tag` model

```
class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__='tags'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80),nullable=False)
    items = db.relationship("Item",
                            secondary=item_tags_association_table,
                            back_populates="tags")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I answered the problem by myself, so the problem is that I'm trying to append a primary key rather than appending the object itself. so in my views.py I created an object to get the data using the primary key that was passed by the input.